# Show image on hover with PHP

Tags: php, image, hyperlink, hover, z-index

I have a small problem with my PHP code and It would be very nice if someone could help me. I want to display an image when hovering over a link. This is the link with the PHP code that I have now:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {the_post_thumbnail();} else if ( has_post_video() ) {the_post_video_image();}?></a>
```

This code shows a image, but I want to execute this code when hovering over the link with the image:

```
<?php echo print_image_function(); ?>
```

The code also shows a image that belongs to a category. I don't want the initial image to disappear I simply want to show the second image on top off the first image when hovering over the first image.

I don't know if it is helpful but I use Wordpress and I am not a PHP expert. I even don't know if this is going to work. Thats why I am asking if somebody can help me with this.

Thanks in advance

**THANKS EVERYONE**

I want to thank everybody that took the time to read my post and helped me by giving their solution.
I didnt exspect so many answers in such a fast time. After spending a few hours trying it to get it to work with PHP, CSS and Javacript, I stumbled upon the following question on this website: [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179412/css-hover-over-on-thumbnails-in-wordpress)

It was exactly where I was looking for and with a few modifications to fit my needs, I got it to work. Sometimes things can be so easy while you are looking for the hard way. So for everyone that has the same problem: You can use one of the solutions that where given by the awesome people here or take a look at the link above.

Thanks again! :)

Comment: Why has no one mentioned CSS and `:hover:after` here?????? Seriously people. BAD USERS! BAD!

Comment: @rlemon haha I was thinking about it, but I did not want to push **too much** on the OP at once.

Comment: People people people does the `hover` and `z-index` tags not just scream the OP wants to see something NOT in js. I might be wrong but common now.

Comment: Normally this isn't something you would do with PHP...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this with CSS (if you so please and this fits with your overall architecture) - here is an example using the :hover condition and :after  pseudo element.
**html**

```
<a href="#" class="foo"><img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e5b801f3e9b405c4feb5a4461aff73c2?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" /></a>​
```

**css**

```
.foo {
    position: relative;
}
.foo:hover:after {
    content: ' ';
    background-image: url(http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ca536e1d909e8d58cba0fdb55be0c6c5?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG);
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;   
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/3kWhf/ demo here

#### Edit:

Always when using new or experimental CSS features reference a compatibility chart http://caniuse.com/ to ensure you are still in your supported browsers. For example, `:after` is only supported starting IE8.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine I always like to let the OP do *some research* :P you're making things too easy.

Answer (score 4):

You **cannot** randomly execute server side code on the client side.

Try using javascript AJAX requests instead.

Comment: what does this even have to do with AJAX

Comment: @rlemon oy... in order to get whatever new info the OP might need from the server.

Comment: Might... but that is not part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a server-side language; you can't get PHP to execute after the page has loaded (because PHP completely finishes parsing before the page loads). If you want hover events, you need JS.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you don't need the `elseif` statement. An `else` will serve the same purpose, unless you intend to have blank  tags where neither a thumbnail or a video image are present.

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <?php 
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) 
        {
            the_post_thumbnail();
        } 
        else
        {
            the_post_video_image();
        }
    ?>
</a>
```

You can't explicitly use PHP for client side functionality. You will need to use javascript or jquery to supply the on hover capability.

Jquery example:

```
$(function() {

    $('a').hover(function() {

        // Code to execute whenever the <a> is hovered over

        // Example: Whenever THIS <a> tag is hovered over, display
        //          the hidden image that has a class of .rollover

        $(this + ' .rollover').fadeIn(300);

    }, function() {

        // Execute this code when the mouse exits the hover area
        // Example (inline with above example)

        $(this + ' .rollover').fadeOut(300);

    });

});
```

To have an image placed on top of another image you would need to make sure your CSS uses `absolute` positioning for the images with the image that is to overlay the other on hover is given a `z-index` value higher than the image to sit underneath it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: all of this can be done with just css. albeit not as cross compatible.. but it can be done.

Comment: Indeed it can, but imho the Jquery method has far more to offer in terms of aesthetics as well as being cross browser compatible.

Answer (score -2):

You'll need some JavaScript and/or CSS to make this work, since PHP is on the server side, not in the client browser.

Comment: jQuery is very common, so I used it in my example.  Anyway, there needs to be some way to store the URL for the hover image.  I chose a JS solution.

Comment: Oopse, sorry.  I missed that when I read the question.  I've removed the specific example from my answer.